# What is the behaviour of "npm install" and "npm update" when changing package.json?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am having trouble grasping why the command "npm update" isn't updating the angular-cli to version 7.3.0, however when I run "npm install" the version of angular-cli is now 7.3.0.

The link below shows the MacOS's terminal output, detailing the version update from angular-cli 6.2.9

[angular-cli update process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP9wu.png)

**package.json file screenshots** *thanks to molamk's feedback*

[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztcf7.png)
[devDependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNYrP.png)

Comment: what's in your `package.json`?

Comment: Btw, there is also the useful `ng update --all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `npm install` and `npm update` by default handle devDependencies
>   differently

`npm install` will install/update devDependencies unless `--production` flag is added.

`npm update` will ignore devDependencies unless `--dev` flag is added

So in your case, you did `npm update` without the `--dev` flag resulted ignores the **angular-cli** version update.

Hope this will help!